# Getting crash while execute numberof sections in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, collections

Hello I am populating an `UICollectionView` but when executing number of section its give me error that

**Error**

> Found nil while unwrapping value

here is my Code

```
var subjects: SubjectResponse?


    func callSubChapAPI(){
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let studentlvl = "student_lvl"
        let student_lvl = preferences.object(forKey: studentlvl) as! String
        print(student_lvl)
        let params = ["level_id": student_lvl]
        Alamofire.request(subListWithChapter, method: .post, parameters: params).responseData() { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

                     self.subjects = try decoder.decode(SubjectResponse.self, from: data)

                    self.collView.reloadData()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ExploreTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {

   func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return self.subjects!.subjectList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.subjects!.subjectList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionViewCell
        let url = subjects!.subjectList[indexPath.section].subList[indexPath.row].chImage
        print(url)
        return cell
    } 
}
```

But I am getting crash so please help me why i am getting crash where I am done wrong

Comment: Don't force unwrap `self.subjects`.  Use `return self.subjects?.subjectList.count ?? 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `numberOfSections` you need to return number of subjects in `subjectList`, if `subjects` is `nil`, return `0`

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return subjects?.subjectList.count ?? 0
}
```

now every subject inside `subjectList` has property which is array `subList`. In `numberOfItemsInSection` return number of elements in `subList` for certain `subjectList` (now you can force-unwrap `subjects` because you know that there is any if `numberOfSections` is more then 0)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return subjects!.subjectList[section].subList.count
}
```